# htaccess is changing url's? gclid=

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, google-ads-api

On my wordpress site I'm not able to use **Google** adwords gclid.

When I go:

```
example.com/?a=gclid=
```

it self-changes to

```
example.com/?a=gclid%3D
```

How to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: `?a=gclid=` - why do you have `a=` here? In this context, `gclid=` is all part of the parameter _value_, so it is arguably correct to URL encode the second `=` as `%3D`. (?)

Comment: It's possible to store GCLID in a session so your data doesn't get diluted by wordpress handling of links https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69570/how-to-pass-on-google-adwords-gclid-variable-to-other-pages